# toLowerCase() has suddenly stopped working in Zapier

Tags: zapier

We have a code-zap that has been running without any problems for over more than a year. However, since the last few weeks this Zap has stared throwing an error on the following line of code:

```js
// error: TypeError: value.toLowerCase is not a function
value.toLowerCase()
```

Does anyone know if anything has changed at the infrastructural level at Zapier's end that explains this error? Perhaps some nodeJS version change, or something.

My understanding is that the input to this function has also not changed. Just to re-confirm this, is there any easy way to log the value of `value`?

Comment: In my opinion this problem happen because your variable data type had been changed and this variable type not string
Can you check data type of variable?

Answer (score 1):

Zapier's Node.js versions *do* change automatically over time. Typically because the version a zap is running is using an EoL version of Node.js.

That said, I don't *think* such an upgrade would change the data type of an input. Something else certainly could have changed though. For debugging purposes, printing out the type of `value` will help show what type it is and how it changed.